# Are we able to play just a certain fragment of mp3 by using MediaElement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

Try to use MediaElement.js for audio player within a html page, but I am not sure whether or not I can use it for playing a certain fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use timeupdate event to listen to time change, stopping playback when it gets say 30 seconds in.

```
mediaElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
  if (mediaElement.currentTime >= 30) {
    mediaElement.stop();
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: how to define the starting time

Comment: mediaElement.setCurrentTime(YourTime) I believe is what you want.